# Robot Java class XP vs. Vista Win7

Tags: java, windows, automation

The following Java code when run on Windows XP will lock the desktop, however when run on Vista or Windows 7 it doesn't lock the desktop. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how to get this to work in Vista and Windows 7 using Java only.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Roboto {
 //Lock windows desktop using "WinKey + L"
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   Robot r = new Robot();
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
  } catch (AWTException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot press Window+L using robot in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193293/cannot-press-windowl-using-robot-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Vista's UAC is preventing the JVM from feeding events into the OS event queue.  Since you didn't mention it, I assume you aren't seeing an exception.  Can you try running this with Administrator privileges?

Comment: Hi Jim, you assumed correctly i do not see an exception. But when I set the javaw.exe file to run with admin privileges I now get the following exception: "Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\sja26\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Page"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: Is "Exception" a Java Exception? How did you "set [it] to run with admin privileges"?