# Cannot press Window+L using robot in Java

Tags: java, windows-8, awtrobot

I am using the Robot class to simulate key press in Java. But i am unable to press Window key+L although i am able to press them individually. Here is my code:

```
private void pressKey()
{
    Robot r=new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
}
```

Comment: @chaitanya10 The methods are the standard [`java.awt.robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) methods.

Comment: @Baz ohh .. i dont know awt :P.. thanks anyways :)

Comment: yeah they are specified in the class itself

Comment: This works for me on XP in that it jumps to the lock screen, but it goes strange afterwards, as if both keys are still stuck down. So while typing in my password to unlock it, L doesn't work and pressing U opens the Utility Manager (Win+U). Pressing the Windows key again clears it up, but maybe what you're trying to do isn't such a good method.

Comment: What should i do to press it then?

Comment: @Boann That's because Windows logs out as soon as both buttons are pressed down. Hence, they are still pressed when you are on your login screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```

Comment: Impressive. Thanx a lot. Works Fine, serves my purpose.

Comment: How this line fix the actual issue? Can you please describe about this line?

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda It tells Windows to invoke the API function [`LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875.aspx), instead of trying to fake it with keypresses.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. Make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void pressKey(){
   Robot r=new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
}
```

Comment: What windows version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.delay(200);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```